# Redirect from current window when sending POST form from javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html

I want to redirect the page in the current window when POST using javascript.
My code opens a new window when POST.
I want to open it in the current window, but I can not find a way...

```
function test() {
    test( function(data) {
        var obj1 = data
        var form = document.createElement("form");
        form.setAttribute("charset", "UTF-8");
        form.setAttribute("method", "Post");
        form.setAttribute("action", "test.php");
        var hiddenField = document.createElement("input");
        hiddenField.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
        hiddenField.setAttribute("name", "raw");
        hiddenField.setAttribute("value", obj1);
        form.appendChild(hiddenField);               
        var url ="test.php"
        var title = "testpop"
        var status = "toolbar=no,directories=no,scrollbars=no,resizable=no,status=no,menubar=no,width=1240, height=1200, top=0,left=20"

        form.target = title;
        document.body.appendChild(form);
        form.submit(function(){
            location.reload();
        });
    } );
}
```

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: I can't understand the use of form.target = title.

Comment: Do not assign any value to `form.target`